# Puppeteer Sharp PDF cutting page issue

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-core, browser, puppeteer

I try to capture a web page to PDF using [Puppeteer Sharp](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/), but I found the page is not fully captured, the bottom part of the browser page is not saved to the PDF file.
[here](https://metabase0-31-2.azurewebsites.net/embed/dashboard/eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyZXNvdXJjZSI6eyJkYXNoYm9hcmQiOjE5fSwicGFyYW1zIjp7InN1cnZleV9pZCI6IjY4NTU3OWY4LTgxOGItNDM2My1jZjFiLTA4ZDYyMzY5NTQ2ZiJ9fQ.kKyrhTPpWnLQYW1l0flmLGj2RF-9cR-JaiP5UbuAcpE#bordered&titled) is web page to capture, which is generated from Metabase dashboard.

below is the code to capture the page:

```
            var options = new ConnectOptions()
            {
                BrowserWSEndpoint = $"wss://chrome.browserless.io"
            };

            var browser = await Puppeteer.ConnectAsync(options);
            var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
            var webpageurl = await GetDashboardUrl(id);
            await page.GoToAsync(webpageurl,
                timeout: 3000000, waitUntil: new WaitUntilNavigation[] { WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle0 });
            var option = new PdfOptions { Width = 1300, Height = 1300*1.41, Landscape=false};

            return await page.PdfStreamAsync(option);
```

I use [Browserless io](https://docs.browserless.io/docs/start.html) as remote browser.
the pdf page cutted as below:
[image]

if I change Height value to a very large value(more than 6000), and the pdf can have all the browser page content, but when I print it, all the content has to print into one page, I need to print them properly.
[image]
anyone can solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an issue on the page. The page is not "print friendly".

Comment: solved this issue by capture the whole page into one page in pdf, and split the pdf file using PDF sharper into pages.

Comment: how did you do that @DenisD? capture the whole page in one pdf